# adding weighted average with aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the data frame below

```
library(ggplot2)
v = c(100,50,50,20,30,100,100,100,40,5)
s = c(1,10, 5, 90,40, 100, 1,1,30,5)
g = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5))
m = c (1,1,5,5,10, 10,10,8,5,2)
d = data.frame(value = v, size= s, group = g, m = m)
d
a  = aggregate(d$v, by = list(d$m, d$g), FUN= mean)
a
ggplot(data=a, aes(x=Group.1, y=x, group=Group.2)) +
  geom_line( )+geom_point()
```

Currently the aggregate() take the average "v" within each "g" and "m" group.

Instead of the simple average I'd like to plot the weighted average using "s" withing each "g" and "m" as the weight. For example in  when g = A and m = 1 then the aggregate returns 75 which is average of 100 & 50 but I'd like to return the weighted average (100*1+50*10)/11  = 54.

What's the best way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  group_by(m, group)  %>%
  summarise(vmean =  floor(weighted.mean(value, size)))
#     m  group vmean
#  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
#1     1      A    54
#2     2      B     5
#3     5      A    21
#4     5      B    40
#5     8      B   100
#6    10      A    30
#7    10      B   100
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
by(d[c("value", "size")], list(d$group, d$m), 
             FUN = function(x) weighted.mean(x[,1], x[,2]))
```